# Как спарсить Steam видео?

Tags: python, steam

Вот есть скрипт на Python. Он парсит страницу в стиме. Вот например: https://store.steampowered.com/app/1151340/Fallout_76/

Я спарсил все html теги от видео и скриншотов. Копирую на свой сайт, но видео нет и скриншоты маленькие. Подскажите, может парсинг работает некорректно?

Comment: может не тот див в парсинг вставляю?

Comment: https://store.steampowered.com/app/1151340/Fallout_76/ вот ссылку вставляю. Но парсить видимо нужно другой класс, не highlight_overflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам следует извлекать не элементы HTML, а источники, которые уже можно использовать как угодно:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = input('Вставьте ссылку на игру: ')


def get_html(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    r.encoding = 'utf8'
    return r.text


def get_link(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    photo = soup.find_all('a', attrs={"class": "highlight_screenshot_link", "href": True})
    video = soup.find_all('div', attrs={"class": "highlight_player_item", "data-mp4-source": True, "data-webm-source": True})

    for item in video:
        print('<video width="640" height="480" controls>')
        print('<source src="' + item["data-mp4-source"] + '" type="video/mp4">')
        print('<source src="' + item["data-webm-source"] + '" type="video/webm">')
        print('</video><br />\n')

    for item in photo:
        print('<img src="' + item['href'] + '" alt="" width="640" /><br />\n')


get_link(get_html(str(link) + '?l=russian'))
```